# Java (Grails) cannot connect to MySQL remotely nor locally, but MySQL command line can

Tags: mysql, tomcat, jakarta-ee, grails

I have setup many MySQL databases on Windows and Linux, and connected many Java applications to them without issue.

This particular one is driving me insane, I have checked all the usual suspects, and come up blank.

**The problem:**

I installed MySQL 5.6 on Ubuntu 14. I can connect to it fine from local machine or remote PC via MySQL command line, but I cannot connect my Grails application to the database, neither running in Tomcat on the local server where MySQL is installed, or running in dev mode on my local PC.  The Grails app connects fine to my local MySQL running on my PC, but not the one running on Ubuntu.

**Ubuntu MySQL configuration:**

1. MySQL 5.6 is installed on Ubuntu 14 via apt-get install mysql-server-5.6
2. CREATE DATABASE mydb;
3. create user 'myuser'@'%' identified by 'mypass';
4. grant all privileges on * . * to 'myuser'@'%';
5. The bind address is commented out in my.cnf, so it binds to all ips.
6. service mysql restart.
7. iptables are not running.
8. ISP firewall not configured for this server, everything wide open.

**Testing connection:**

1. from Local server: "mysql -u myuser -p mydb" - works and can create tables etc.
2. as above from remote PC running windows via: "mysql -u myuser -p -h x.x.x.x mydb" where x.x.x.x is the IP of my server.  Works fine.  Can create tables etc.

The above implies that MySQL is running fine, that there are no firewalls or networking issues.

**the Grails "DataSource.groovy" configuration**

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
} 
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop"
            url = "jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x:3306/mydb"
            username = "myuser"
            password = "mypass"
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE:

- Also tried:       url = "jdbc:mysql://x.x.x.x/mydb"
- The JDBC jar is:  mysql-connector-java-5.1.34.jar
- The Java used is: Windows jkd1.7.0_60

**The error**

```
Message: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    Line | Method
->>  377 | handleNewInstance             in com.mysql.jdbc.Util
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1036 | createCommunicationsException in com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError
|    338 | <init> . . . . . . . . . . .  in com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO
|   2232 | coreConnect                   in com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl
```

**Logs:**
There is nothing related in the file /var/log/upstart/mysql.log nor var/log/mysql/error.log on the server.

**The million dollar question is:** Why would MySQL be able to connect, but JDBC not?  What is the difference between the way they work (both from local and remote machines)?

[This post](https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally) has the most information about this issue, but I have not found any solution.

Also tried this:

```
properties {
    maxActive = -1
    minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
    timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
    numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
    testOnBorrow=true
    testWhileIdle=true
    testOnReturn=true
    validationQuery="SELECT 1"
}
```

**Running the Grails war on Tomcat on the same server as the DB**

I have more or less the same error,  but different Java, different OS, different connection method.

**Tomcat7 /var/lib/tomcat7/conf/context.xml**

```
<Resource name="myresource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="50" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000"
    username="myuser" password="mypass" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
```

**Grails configuration**

```
environments {
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            jndiName = "java:comp/env/myresource"
            pooled = true
            driverClassName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            dialect = "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
            properties {
                maxActive = -1
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
                numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
                testOnBorrow=true
                testWhileIdle=true
                testOnReturn=true
                validationQuery="SELECT 1"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The error in /var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out**

```
2015-01-16 23:18:41,425 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR pool.ConnectionPool  - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Driver:com.mysql.jdbc.Driver@52fc036d returned null for URL:jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:296)
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:182)
```

Interestingly, the above mentions h2:mem db, but I think this is only a red-herring, its perhaps trying that after trying to connect to the MySQL db.  There is no mention of h2 db anywhere in the DataSource.groovy file.

NOTE:

Java on the server (same as MySQL server) is OpenJDK, not Oracle's:

```
# apt-get install openjdk-7-jre-headless
# java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.5.3) (7u71-2.5.3-0ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

JDBC (don't know how to verify the version)

```
# apt-get install libmysql-java
# cp /usr/share/java/mysql.jar /usr/share/tomcat7/lib
```

I have tried the following bind options in my.cnf (separately, with restart)

```
bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
bind-address           = x.x.x.x (i.e. my servers external fixed ip)
bind-address           = 0.0.0.0
# bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
```

all give the same error. On a dev server, I generally leave it with the bind-address commented out, so it listens on all interfaces.

I also checked that:

```
TOMCAT7_SECURITY=no
```

in /etc/init.d/tomcat7

Comment: The reason it works from the commandline and not Grails is Grails is misconfigured, but it's not clear where. Having `jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000` in the error is very much not a red herring. That indicates that no datasource information was found, so Grails is using default values. Try `grails clean` and `grails compile` - my guess is something isn't compiling because of a typo and a full recompile should show that. I'd go further and `rm -rf target` instead of running clean - that'll remove all generated files and trigger a plugin reinstall in addition to recompiling.

Comment: Try running `grails console` and executing `println ctx.grailsApplication.config.dataSource`. Shut it down and run `grails prod console` and run that again. That will show you what the resolved settings are for the different environments' datasources.

Comment: grails console is good idea.   However, when I run it with prod env (which is just a different ip for the db), it gives that stack trace then no console comes up. When I run it for dev with the ip of my local mysql, I get the console, and typing in println ctx... works.

Comment: @BurtBeckwith Cracked it! following your logic, realized where the problem is.  I have a plugin core which has all DB logic. I have an app which uses that plugin.  I was editing the DataSource.groovy in the plugin, thinking that was the one.  but its using the Datasource.groovy in the calling app.  Doh!

Comment: Yep, Grails is annoying in that regard - always doing what you told it to do, and not what you meant to tell it to do :)

Comment: try to run clean using the grails command

Answer (score 2):

I've bumped into a similar issue.

Just to clarify line in the reported error log:

```
URL:jdbc:h2:mem:grailsDB;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000
```

This DB connection URL seems to be DataSource's default one which is used when you don't specify any valid URL in your custom DataSource. This means, when you see this URL in the log, you haven't specified any valid URL for your DB.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue.
I upgraded the the MySql dependency version and driver class name as below:

FROM:

mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36

com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

TO:

mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.18

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver